# function com erro ao retorna alert

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tenho um `function` que se ela retorna `1` aparece um `alert`:

> formulário foi enviado com sucesso

Se retorna `0`, aparece um `alert`:

> erro ao enviar seu formulário.

Quando eu deixo o formulário em branco o comportamento esperado seria exibir o alert de erro "erro ao enviar seu formulário" e não mandar nada no banco, mas está acontecendo ao contrario mesmo dando o alert de erro está enviando o formulário em branco pro banco.

```
  <?php 

if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nise', $username );



    $query = "INSERT INTO denuncia (descricao, imagem, id_usuario, qual_descricao,id_bloco, id_denuncia_oque) 
          VALUES (:descricao, :imagem, :id_usuario, :qual_descricao, :id_bloco, :id_denuncia_oque)";



    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);





    $path = "img_denuncia/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path))



    $valores = array();
    $valores[':descricao'] = $_POST['descricao_denuncia'];
    $valores[':imagem'] = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $valores[':id_usuario'] = 2;
    $valores[':qual_descricao'] = $_POST['qual_descricao'];
    $valores[':id_bloco'] = $_POST['bloco_denuncia'];
    $valores[':id_denuncia_oque'] = $_POST['id_denuncia_oque'];

    if(!isset($_POST['descricao_denuncia']) or empty($_POST['descricao_denuncia'])) {

        echo 0;

}   elseif(!isset($_POST['qual_descricao']) or empty($_POST['qual_descricao'])) {

        echo 0;

}   elseif(!isset($_POST['bloco_denuncia']) or empty($_POST['bloco_denuncia'])) {

        echo 0;

}   elseif(!isset($_POST['id_denuncia_oque']) or empty($_POST['id_denuncia_oque'])) {

        echo 0;

}   elseif($result = $statement->execute($valores)) {

        echo 1; // dados enviados com sucesso

}   else {

        echo 0; // erro ao tentar enviar dados 

}






}
?>
```

function

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // evento de "submit"
                $("#b_enviar").click(function (e) {
                    // parar o envio para que possamos faze-lo manualmente.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // captura o formulário
                    var form = $('#caixa')[0];
                    // cria um FormData {Object}
                    var data = new FormData(form);
                    // processar
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/nise/aluno.php", //acerte o caminho para seu script php
                        data: data,
                        processData: false, // impedir que o jQuery tranforma a "data" em querystring
                        contentType: false, // desabilitar o cabeçalho "Content-Type"
                        //cache: false, // desabilitar o "cache"
                        // manipular o sucesso da requisição
                    }).done(function(retorno){
                        console.log(retorno);
                        retorno = parseInt(retorno);  


                        if(retorno==1)
                          {
                            //alert("Formulário enviado com sucesso");
                            $("#myModalSucess").modal('show');
                             console.log(retorno);   
                          }
                           else
                          {
                            //alert("erro ao enviar formulário");
                            $("#myModalError").modal('show'); 


                          }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>
```

form

```
 <form id="caixa" class="center-block row col-xl-6" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario"  method="POST" action="aluno.php">
                <br>
                  <div class="row p-0 no-margin col-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="sel1">Bloco:</label>
                      <select class="form-control " name="bloco_denuncia" id="bloco" required="required" placeholder="ex: Bloco 3" >
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Ex: Computação</option>
                        <option value="1">Bloco - Computação</option>
                        <option value="2">Bloco - Mecânica</option>
                        <option value="3">Bloco - Química</option>
                        <option value="4">Bloco - Administrativo</option>
                        <option value="5">Biblioteca </option>
                        <option value="6">Ginásio </option>
                        <option value="7">Auditório</option>
                        <option value="0">Outros</option>
                      </select>
                      </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="sel1">O que:</label>
                      <select select="required" class="form-control" name="id_denuncia_oque" id="sel1" required="required" >
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Ex: Laboratório</option>
                        <option value="1">Sala</option>
                        <option value="2">Banheiro(Térreo)</option>
                        <option value="3">Banheiro(Superior)</option>
                        <option value="4">Laboratório</option>
                        <option value="5">Coordenação</option>
                        <option value="6">Gabinete</option>
                        <option value="7">Telecom</option>
                        <option value="8">Outros</option>

                      </select>
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Qual:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" name="qual_descricao" placeholder="Ex: Lab" required="required" >
                        </div>

                  </div>
                   <textarea id="noresize" class="form-control col-12 col-sm-12 mb-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12 " name="descricao_denuncia" placeholder="Faça sua denúncia aqui... " rows="13" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea>

                   <br>
                   <div id="botoes" class="row p-0 no-margin col-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12">  
                        <div class="botao p-0 no-margin col-6 col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xl-10">
                       <label class="file-upload btn btn-primary">
                            Escolha o arquivo... <input  type="file" name="uploaded_file"/ accept="image/*">
                        </label>  
                       <small class="form-text text-muted">As suas mensagens não serão totalmente anônimas.</small>
                        </div>
                      <div class="botao p-0 no-margin col-6 col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-6 col-lg-10 col-xl-2 text-right ">
                           <input id="b_enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar" name="enviar"/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <br>
                <!--Fim da caixa-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que fazer uma verificação se o input foi deixado em branco, você pode fazer com os seguintes estilos:

Verifica se o input foi enviado, caso não da `echo 0;`:

```
if(!isset($input)) {
   echo 0;
}
```

Verifica se o input foi deixado em branco, caso sim, da `echo 0;`:

```
if(trim($input) == '') {
   echo 0;
}
```

Verifica se o input foi deixado em branco, caso sim, da `echo 0;` (apenas uma maneira diferente):

```
if(empty($input)) {
   echo 0;
}
```

No seu código você poderia mudar aquele `if($result = $statement->execute($valores))` e fazer da seguinte forma:

**Neste código, você tem a liberdade de fazer um echo diferente para cada input vazio, assim podendo especificar ao usuário oque ele deixou vazio.**

```
if(!isset($_POST['descricao_denuncia']) or empty($_POST['descricao_denuncia'])) {

    echo 0;

} elseif(!isset($_POST['qual_descricao']) or empty($_POST['qual_descricao'])) {

    echo 0;

} elseif(!isset($_POST['bloco_denuncia']) or empty($_POST['bloco_denuncia'])) {

    echo 0;

} elseif(!isset($_POST['id_denuncia_oque']) or empty($_POST['id_denuncia_oque'])) {

    echo 0;

} elseif($result = $statement->execute($valores)) {

    echo 1; // dados enviados com sucesso

} else {

    echo 0; // erro ao tentar enviar dados 

}
```

**Caso você queria fazer `echo 0` independente do campo que foi deixado em branco, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:**

```
if(!isset($_POST['descricao_denuncia']) or empty($_POST['descricao_denuncia']) or !isset($_POST['qual_descricao']) or empty($_POST['qual_descricao']) or !isset($_POST['bloco_denuncia']) or empty($_POST['bloco_denuncia']) or !isset($_POST['id_denuncia_oque']) or empty($_POST['id_denuncia_oque'])) {

    echo 0;

} elseif($result = $statement->execute($valores)) {

    echo 1; // dados enviados com sucesso

} else {

    echo 0; // erro ao tentar enviar dados 

}
```

Comment: Obrigado resolveu meu problema, mas quando o formulário é enviado os campos não estão limpando, vou posta o código atualizado, e você ver se eu eu coloquei no local certo.

Comment: @PauloVictor novamente, não é um bug, você tem que programar isso. é só pesquisar como apagar inputs com jquery

Comment: Obrigado, pensei que seria erros, vou pesquisa. Obrigado